# MySQL Workbench 8: Set different colors for database connections

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm looking for a configuration that protects me to avoid running the wrong commands in the wrong databases.

I used a simple feature in SQL Server Management Studio that allowed me to set colours for connections like this example: [image: example showing coloured status bar]

Is it possible to do the same or similar configuration on MySQL Workbench 8?

I found [this question](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,655499,655506) about this feature posted in 2017 and at this moment it wasn't possible. But I didn't find anything recently.

Comment: I don't have an Appearance option in the Connection tab